# Book about a girl with violet eyes who discovers she's living in a simulation of the 1980s

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, dystopia

I remember a book I read in school about a girl with violet eyes who is growing up in the 80s. She is incredibly smart and always compared to a violet eyed boy who is a grade above her, but she couldn't meet him.

As the story goes on, she meets him and they uncover together that they are in a simulation of the 80s and they were sent there to basically prevent them from developing their full abilities. They discover a whole network of violet-eyed children who were sent to various pretend simulations in the past and uncover an intense, technologically advanced dystopia as they try to escape from the simulated world and their parents.

Some specifics I remember are a friend of the girl accidently saying "chunks" instead of "hunks." I forget the main characters' names but there is also a discussion of them choosing their families from like a line up in a memory that for most of their life they forgot. The girl remembers choosing a couple she thought would be loving, and the male protagonist remembers choosing a family he wouldn't miss when he inevitably escaped and ran away.

They become great at a sport and are able to attend some kind of national competition where they carry out an escape plan.

This is all I reliably remember. Any one have any idea the title/author of this book? I read it in the late 90s.

Answer (score 10):

Is this ***[Violet Eyes](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/478625.Violet_Eyes)*** (2001) by Nicole Luiken...? It's the first book in the *[Violet Eyes](https://www.goodreads.com/series/63540-violet-eyes)* series.

The summary for the first book mentions a female protagonist named Angel Eastland and a male protagonist named Michael Valiant, both of whom have violet eyes:

> **It is more than her violet eyes that makes Angel Eastland different from the other kids and when she meets Michael Vallant, who also has violet eyes,** Angel realizes they are both very different and both in danger. Original.
>
> [image: Front cover of "Violet Eyes" (2001) by Nicole Luiken.]

The summary for the third book, *[Angel Eyes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8SRd.jpg)* (2013), mentions that both characters were unknowingly raised in a "1980s Historical Immersion project," from which they escaped:

> Mike and Angel are not like other teens. Born with violet eyes, highly intelligent and athletically gifted, they belong to a genetically-engineered superspecies. Though **raised in ignorance in a 1980s Historical Immersion project, they escaped their prison.** After months on the run, Mike and Angel have found a fragile peace, attending college, but diverging careers have driven a wedge between them.

I checked the [Google Books preview](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Violet_Eyes/qnVV93BU7QUC?hl=en&gbpv=0) of the book and found the following excerpt, regarding the girl who said 'chunks' instead of 'hunks:'

> I kissed his chin, murmuring, "And come to think of it, when Maryanne first moved to Chinchaga **she called good-looking boys 'chunks' instead of 'hunks.'**"